# SQL SMS to calculate time difference between work lines

Tags: ssms

Ok after a few tips Im going to revise this question, hopefully this is a little more clear.

Im looking for a way to query data so that I can calculate the number of lines per movement type but also the cumulative time a shipment's lines take. This is would be an example of what Im looking for:

`Shipment ID    # of SO Picks   SO Pick Time    # of Stage Lines    Stage Time  # of Packing lines  Packing Time    Total time of shipment
SH-000026373    1   0:13    (Null)  (Null)  (Null)  (Null)  0:13
SH-000026504    1   0:20    (Null)  (Null)  (Null)  (Null)  0:20
SH-000029530    3   973:17:08   2   22:57:47    2   22:58:55    996:16:16
SH-000038973    13  2:06:01 (Null)  (Null)  9   0:02:19 165:00:28
SH-000043978    305 45:42:57    (Null)  (Null)  (Null)  (Null)  45:42:57`

Currently I pull data from the WorkLines table with this query...

`select shipmentid, itemid, qtywork, wmslocationid, workclassid, workstatus, workclosedutcdatetime, worktype
from whsworkline
where workclosedutcdatetime > '8/16/2017' and workclosedutcdatetime < '10/15/2017' and 
(workclassid = 'so pick' or workclassid = 'Stage' or workclassid = 'Packing')
order by shipmentid, workclosedutcdatetime`

And I get the following data...

`shipmentid itemid  qtywork wmslocationid   workclassid workstatus  workclosedutcdatetime   worktype
SH-000026373    96001900490000  32  24-20-5-1   SO PICK 4   9/23/2017 15:06:07  1
SH-000026373    96001900490000  32  P1  SO PICK 4   9/23/2017 15:06:20  2
SH-000026504    20182302000422  12  22-50-5-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 10:29:30  1
SH-000026504    20182302000422  12  P1  SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 10:29:50  2
SH-000029530    91039700060095  48  14-4-4-1    SO PICK 4   8/17/2017 2:04:45   1
SH-000029530    91047209251095  14  23-5-7-1    SO PICK 4   8/17/2017 2:10:50   1
SH-000029530        62  L1  SO PICK 4   8/17/2017 2:10:55   2
SH-000029530    91047112251095  184 15-24-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/26/2017 15:21:52  1
SH-000029530    91047112251095  184 L1  SO PICK 4   9/26/2017 15:21:53  2
SH-000029530    91047112251095  184 L1  STAGE   4   9/26/2017 15:21:58  1
SH-000029530    91047112251095  184 S1  STAGE   4   9/26/2017 15:21:59  2
SH-000029530    91047112251095  184 BULKPACK    PACKING 4   9/26/2017 15:22:06  2
SH-000029530    91047112251095  184 S1  PACKING 4   9/26/2017 15:22:06  1
SH-000029530        62  L1  STAGE   4   9/27/2017 14:19:40  1
SH-000029530        62  S1  STAGE   4   9/27/2017 14:19:45  2
SH-000029530        62  S1  PACKING 4   9/27/2017 14:20:29  1
SH-000029530        62  P1  PACKING 4   9/27/2017 14:21:01  2
SH-000038973    21198245412430  132 4-14-5-2    SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 19:21:35  1
SH-000038973    21198245412430  18  2-51-4-2    SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 19:27:58  1
SH-000038973        150 L10 SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 19:44:40  2
SH-000038973    21177248812430  72  38-60-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 19:54:58  1
SH-000038973    21177248812430  29  39-31-5-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 20:14:53  1
SH-000038973        101 L10 SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 20:15:34  2
SH-000038973    21177248812430  54  38-16-3-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 20:27:39  1
SH-000038973    21177248812430  45  39-23-4-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 20:30:07  1
SH-000038973        99  L10 SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 20:42:18  2
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  42-55-3-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 20:47:39  1
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  L10 SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 20:47:49  2
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  42-58-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 21:00:21  1
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  L10 SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 21:00:34  2
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  42-61-3-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 21:06:36  1
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  L10 SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 21:07:05  2
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  42-62-3-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 21:11:18  1
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  L10 SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 21:15:26  2
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  48-6-1-1    SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 21:18:47  1
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  L10 SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 21:20:52  2
SH-000038973    91019423061625  26  42-39-4-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 21:25:00  1
SH-000038973    91019423061625  24  46-28-4-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 21:27:31  1
SH-000038973    91019423061625  50  L10 SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 21:27:36  2
SH-000038973    91019423061625  50  L10 PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:19:44  1
SH-000038973    91019423061625  50  P1  PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:19:48  2
SH-000038973        150 L10 PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:19:59  1
SH-000038973        150 P1  PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:20:04  2
SH-000038973        101 L10 PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:20:14  1
SH-000038973        101 P1  PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:20:16  2
SH-000038973        99  L10 PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:20:24  1
SH-000038973        99  P1  PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:20:27  2
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  L10 PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:21:02  1
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  P1  PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:21:06  2
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  L10 PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:21:17  1
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  P1  PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:21:20  2
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  L10 PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:21:28  1
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  P1  PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:21:38  2
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  L10 PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:21:48  1
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  P1  PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:21:51  2
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  L10 PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:22:00  1
SH-000038973    91019423061625  80  P1  PACKING 4   9/26/2017 16:22:03  2
SH-000043978    91007210490000  72  22-22-4-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 11:46:55  1
SH-000043978    91007210060000  19  22-22-4-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 11:53:15  1
SH-000043978    91007210310000  54  22-23-4-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 11:59:13  1
SH-000043978    USECC250    240 23-47-5-3   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 12:13:52  1
SH-000043978    91007210060000  53  25-8-4-2    SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 12:17:29  1
SH-000043978        438 P1  SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 12:17:35  2
SH-000043978    91026100426000  27  4-6-2-3 SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 13:03:32  1
SH-000043978    92100022310000  4   DR28    SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 13:13:29  1
SH-000043978    92100022310000  2   DR28    SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 13:14:32  1
SH-000043978    96002000536000  4   DR3 SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 13:17:54  1
SH-000043978    96211040000100  3   DR25    SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 13:20:32  1
SH-000043978    91004923370100  1   DR24    SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 13:22:50  1
SH-000043978    91001533310025  1   18-50-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 13:26:34  1
SH-000043978    92009600426000  1   18-33-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 13:28:10  1
SH-000043978    91001404060025  3   18-33-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 13:30:36  1
SH-000043978    91049924310099  2   18-25-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 13:32:11  1
SH-000043978    93007404730000  4   17-2-1-5    SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 13:36:04  1
SH-000043978    20136272000460  1   17-4-4-2    SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:09:24  1
SH-000043978    20182232000422  2   17-5-3-3    SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:09:59  1
SH-000043978    59989016000625  21  17-6-4-5    SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:13:09  1
SH-000043978    21180300101430  1   17-8-1-2    SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:13:47  1
SH-000043978    93004616000000  10  17-11-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:15:58  1
SH-000043978    91028500444005  2   17-11-4-3   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:18:04  1
SH-000043978    91007240310000  15  17-15-4-3   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:22:24  1
SH-000043978    93010200060000  12  17-17-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:23:39  1
SH-000043978    94034570000001  30  17-21-4-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:25:46  1
SH-000043978    25180222002422  1   17-22-4-3   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:26:17  1
SH-000043978    93010300310000  12  17-23-3-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:27:59  1
SH-000043978    91008600310000  3   17-24-2-3   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:29:28  1
SH-000043978    91007210370000  24  17-24-2-5   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:31:38  1
SH-000043978    91007210090000  24  17-24-3-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:32:36  1
SH-000043978    20164340600460  1   17-29-3-4   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:36:55  1
SH-000043978    91007900090000  4   17-31-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:39:38  1
SH-000043978    91041926403000  6   17-32-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:42:16  1
SH-000043978    91015800490000  2   17-37-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:43:59  1
SH-000043978    98401200000000  3   17-37-4-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:44:50  1
SH-000043978    25097282002460  1   17-51-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:45:23  1
SH-000043978    95003440090300  12  17-52-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:46:20  1
SH-000043978    91041836403000  2   16-46-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:48:05  1
SH-000043978    91041918403000  3   16-44-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:48:40  1
SH-000043978    91042332060000  1   16-41-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:51:01  1
SH-000043978    91042332426000  1   16-41-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:51:31  1
SH-000043978    91014900426210  1   16-36-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:53:26  1
SH-000043978    91005000426000  24  16-35-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:56:53  1
SH-000043978    91005723426100  2   16-33-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 14:59:25  1
SH-000043978    25178354262422  1   16-29-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:00:25  1
SH-000043978    25138350600422  3   16-28-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:05:54  1
SH-000043978        277 P1  SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:06:15  2
SH-000043978    20182300900422  1   16-16-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:22:58  1
SH-000043978    25177284262422  1   16-16-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:23:23  1
SH-000043978    91000410090900  4   16-12-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:24:31  1
SH-000043978    91010038310145  2   15-11-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:27:55  1
SH-000043978    92001300536000  3   15-21-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:30:29  1
SH-000043978    91006223426100  3   15-23-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:31:55  1
SH-000043978    91015800310000  10  15-24-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:35:42  1
SH-000043978    91000410426426  4   15-27-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:43:31  1
SH-000043978    91004020426100  4   15-30-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:44:58  1
SH-000043978    91004036426100  3   15-31-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:47:43  1
SH-000043978    91008408426400  4   15-38-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:51:53  1
SH-000043978    91007900426000  4   15-41-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:54:22  1
SH-000043978    91028200490005  1   15-42-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:54:42  1
SH-000043978    20188204262422  2   15-44-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:55:28  1
SH-000043978    91028200140005  1   15-44-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:55:53  1
SH-000043978    91007202426099  24  15-46-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:56:26  1
SH-000043978    91041932310000  3   15-47-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:57:59  1
SH-000043978    21178290101430  1   15-49-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 15:58:28  1
SH-000043978    91041926010000  6   15-49-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 16:01:41  1
SH-000043978    91049924536099  2   15-50-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 16:11:26  1
SH-000043978    91019423310025  4   15-50-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 16:16:39  1
SH-000043978    91042024310000  1   15-50-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 16:17:46  1
SH-000043978    91042332010025  6   15-51-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 16:20:01  1
SH-000043978    91041918010000  4   15-52-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 16:21:22  1
SH-000043978    25097280602460  2   14-2-1-2    SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 16:22:38  1
SH-000043978    91049924060099  4   14-5-1-2    SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 16:24:51  1
SH-000043978    92000900010000  5   13-2-1-2    SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 17:09:53  1
SH-000043978    91041828060000  4   14-16-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 17:12:08  1
SH-000043978    91049906310099  2   13-10-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 17:13:21  1
SH-000043978    91007202090099  24  14-18-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 17:15:17  1
SH-000043978    91049906403099  4   14-19-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 17:16:18  1
SH-000043978        143 P1  SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 17:17:32  2
SH-000043978    91026100426000  9   4-6-2-3 SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 17:45:29  1
SH-000043978    91007202010099  12  14-19-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 17:47:44  1
SH-000043978    20132400600460  6   14-21-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 17:49:34  1
SH-000043978    91001909310000  9   13-17-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 17:54:18  1
SH-000043978    96002000010000  2   13-17-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 17:59:48  1
SH-000043978    93005100426200  2   14-23-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:00:54  1
SH-000043978    91049906010099  6   13-19-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:02:25  1
SH-000043978    91031800060005  2   13-19-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:05:33  1
SH-000043978    91031800310005  1   13-20-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:06:35  1
SH-000043978    20142240000460  2   13-22-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:07:55  1
SH-000043978    91006223490125  2   14-30-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:10:59  1
SH-000043978    21178230101430  1   14-32-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:11:30  1
SH-000043978    91007210222000  24  13-29-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:13:03  1
SH-000043978    91041918060000  12  14-35-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:17:14  1
SH-000043978    20182260100422  1   14-42-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:18:43  1
SH-000043978    91034607060099  6   14-42-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:21:25  1
SH-000043978    91042024490000  1   13-35-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:23:30  1
SH-000043978    21180304442430  1   14-45-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:24:10  1
SH-000043978    96002100490000  1   13-37-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:26:46  1
SH-000043978    96200130000100  1   14-45-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:28:08  1
SH-000043978    96002000310000  3   13-38-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:29:32  1
SH-000043978    25181180602422  1   14-46-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:30:25  1
SH-000043978    91044402426000  6   14-47-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:31:47  1
SH-000043978    91007520310305  6   14-50-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:32:39  1
SH-000043978    91034500510005  3   14-51-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:33:16  1
SH-000043978    91019423426025  2   14-51-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:33:35  1
SH-000043978    96002000090000  2   13-45-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:36:22  1
SH-000043978    96002000140000  2   13-48-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:37:32  1
SH-000043978    91041932010000  3   13-49-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:39:20  1
SH-000043978    91033052490099  30  13-51-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:41:32  1
SH-000043978    91015924490100  3   12-50-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:42:44  1
SH-000043978    10006002000060  1   12-49-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:42:57  1
SH-000043978    91028500060005  1   12-48-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:43:46  1
SH-000043978    91041926490000  10  12-47-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:46:32  1
SH-000043978    20182262000422  1   12-47-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:46:49  1
SH-000043978    91049906426099  2   12-44-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:47:56  1
SH-000043978    91001533490025  4   12-44-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:49:15  1
SH-000043978    25177241702422  2   12-42-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:51:39  1
SH-000043978    91005720010100  3   12-36-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:52:34  1
SH-000043978    96200230000100  1   12-33-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 18:54:10  1
SH-000043978    91000310310000  9   12-33-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 19:02:11  1
SH-000043978        196 P1  SO PICK 4   9/19/2017 19:08:20  2
SH-000043978    91008600370000  2   12-32-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:33:07  1
SH-000043978    91028200444005  1   12-28-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:33:51  1
SH-000043978    20136270600460  1   12-24-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:34:44  1
SH-000043978    91004732010125  1   12-21-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:35:13  1
SH-000043978    91010038091405  4   12-19-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:37:11  1
SH-000043978    91001909060000  16  12-12-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:38:55  1
SH-000043978    21177240101430  2   12-12-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:39:17  1
SH-000043978    20182302000422  1   12-9-1-2    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:42:11  1
SH-000043978    91034607310099  4   12-8-2-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:42:48  1
SH-000043978    91049906060099  4   12-6-2-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:43:37  1
SH-000043978    91015800090000  8   12-4-1-2    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:45:00  1
SH-000043978    96002000490000  2   12-3-1-2    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:46:15  1
SH-000043978    96002000060000  4   12-3-1-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:47:09  1
SH-000043978    96001900060000  6   12-2-1-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:47:31  1
SH-000043978    91033052060099  18  12-1-2-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:49:27  1
SH-000043978    91007210426000  24  11-1-1-2    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:50:40  1
SH-000043978    20188324442422  1   11-1-2-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:50:58  1
SH-000043978    25181164032422  2   11-7-2-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:51:45  1
SH-000043978    91049906090099  3   11-15-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:52:55  1
SH-000043978    91025054060000  5   11-17-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:54:24  1
SH-000043978    9200090044000   2   11-20-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:55:17  1
SH-000043978    91036014060005  2   11-22-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:55:37  1
SH-000043978    91044404010000  4   11-27-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 11:57:22  1
SH-000043978    91027500490100  2   11-27-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:04:08  1
SH-000043978    25177280902422  3   11-30-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:06:47  1
SH-000043978    91041918490000  12  11-30-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:08:46  1
SH-000043978    93007300060000  12  11-32-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:09:32  1
SH-000043978    25157242002460  1   11-34-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:09:48  1
SH-000043978    93007300010000  12  11-34-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:10:58  1
SH-000043978    92009500536000  1   11-35-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:12:18  1
SH-000043978    91028212010005  1   11-41-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:13:21  1
SH-000043978    93007400010000  6   11-44-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:16:05  1
SH-000043978    91013915060000  2   11-45-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:17:46  1
SH-000043978    91041828490000  3   11-52-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:20:50  1
SH-000043978    21177344442430  1   10-52-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:21:19  1
SH-000043978    20188244442422  1   10-51-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:27:53  1
SH-000043978    25180322002422  1   10-51-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:28:33  1
SH-000043978    25177300902422  1   10-51-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:43:20  1
SH-000043978    21308324260430  1   10-47-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:43:49  1
SH-000043978    20182160000422  3   10-46-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:44:20  1
SH-000043978    91004732090125  1   10-46-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:53:41  1
SH-000043978    96600226000000  1   10-45-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:57:22  1
SH-000043978    91031800090005  1   10-36-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:57:53  1
SH-000043978    91007202401099  6   10-36-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:58:10  1
SH-000043978    91019100060000  3   10-35-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 12:59:29  1
SH-000043978    91007202213099  16  10-34-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 13:00:56  1
SH-000043978    91035311090700  4   10-33-1-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 13:02:35  1
SH-000043978    20182264440422  1   10-31-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 13:03:05  1
SH-000043978    96002000541000  2   10-30-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 13:04:25  1
SH-000043978    91005000140700  12  10-27-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 13:05:02  1
SH-000043978    91015800010000  10  10-21-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 13:10:28  1
SH-000043978    96002000426000  2   10-19-2-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 13:16:55  1
SH-000043978        239 P1  SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 13:19:19  2
SH-000043978    20182261700422  3   10-18-2-1   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 13:34:49  1
SH-000043978    91001402536025  4   10-17-1-2   SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 13:36:00  1
SH-000043978    25180302002422  1   10-9-1-2    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 13:36:33  1
SH-000043978    25177302002422  3   10-9-1-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 13:37:11  1
SH-000043978    91000310060000  4   10-6-1-2    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 13:38:20  1
SH-000043978    91042332090025  1   10-4-1-2    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:12:27  1
SH-000043978    91007900310000  8   10-2-1-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:13:43  1
SH-000043978    96001900403000  8   9-6-1-1 SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:15:14  1
SH-000043978    92009600010000  2   9-18-1-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:16:59  1
SH-000043978    20182300600422  8   9-23-1-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:26:34  1
SH-000043978    20182260600422  1   9-24-1-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:26:52  1
SH-000043978    91014900310210  4   9-27-1-2    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:28:07  1
SH-000043978    25177240902422  4   9-37-1-2    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:29:58  1
SH-000043978    91015800536000  6   9-43-1-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:32:21  1
SH-000043978    91001909490000  10  9-45-2-2    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:34:29  1
SH-000043978    91014900490210  12  9-48-2-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:42:49  1
SH-000043978    20142240600460  2   9-49-2-2    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:43:04  1
SH-000043978    91041918090000  10  9-51-1-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:45:26  1
SH-000043978    91034607010099  12  9-51-2-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:48:27  1
SH-000043978    96002000256000  2   8-51-1-2    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:50:27  1
SH-000043978    91004732490100  1   8-49-2-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:52:56  1
SH-000043978    96001900426000  4   8-47-1-2    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:53:32  1
SH-000043978    91044401426000  6   8-44-2-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:55:18  1
SH-000043978    25177140602422  6   8-42-2-2    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:57:51  1
SH-000043978    96001900213000  4   8-37-1-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:58:34  1
SH-000043978    21177280101430  1   8-35-1-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 14:59:37  1
SH-000043978    91005713490100  6   8-30-1-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 15:01:35  1
SH-000043978    92009500060000  4   8-24-1-2    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 15:04:53  1
SH-000043978    92009600310000  1   8-21-1-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 15:07:35  1
SH-000043978    91005723090100  3   8-20-1-2    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 15:08:29  1
SH-000043978        141 P1  SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 15:10:09  2
SH-000043978    92009600060000  3   8-16-1-1    SO PICK 4   9/20/2017 15:17:23  1`

Here are a few informational bullet points about that data:
 - The "WorkType" is either a Pick (1) or a Put (2)
 - The "WorkClassID" is the type of movement within a shipment.
   - Some of our orders have just one type of movement, meaning they get picked and go straight from the Pickface to the Pack Station.
   - Some of our other orders have 2 and 3 movements, meaning they get picked and put to a secondary handling area to get labeled. Then they have another movement (Stage) to move it from the label area to a pooling area. And then a Third movement (Packing) to move it from the pooling area when the packing area.

I feel like it should be easy enough to calculate the time difference between two lines (Maybe using Datediff perhaps) and that would be enough for shipments with only one line. However, I need to be able to calculate several different things to get the desired results from the first example...

1) I need to know the cumulative total time from first pick (work type 1) to the last put (work type 2) within each movement (WorkClassID's "SO Pick", "Stage", "Packing").
 2) I need to know the cumulative time from the first pick of the entire shipment to the very last put of the shipment. And it cannot be a sum of the all the times calculated for the shipment because there are significant gaps between each "WorkClassID". I need to fold those gaps into my calculation for total time.

To tie everything from my "Example of what Im looking for" back to these statements, I am trying to build a report that will be able to tell me...

1) Orders for this customer take X amount of time to pick
 2) Orders for this customer take X amount of time to label
 3) Orders for this customer take X amount of time in the warehouse

I really appreciate help here, thanks for your time.

Ok so after a bunch of help from Daniel this is where I am currently at with my SQL query. Had to change up a few things but his base idea was great...

`select whsworkline.shipmentid as 'Shipment ID', whsworkline.ordernum as 'Order Num', salestable.custaccount 'Customer Acct', whswaveline.waveid as 'Wave ID', whswavetable.wavetemplatename as 'Wave Template',
 count(case when whsworkline.workclassid='so pick' and whsworkline.worktype='1' then whsworkline.itemid else null end ) as 'Pick Lines',

convert(varchar, datediff(second,min(case when whsworkline.workclassid = 'so pick' then whsworkline.WORKINPROCESSUTCDATETIME else null end), max(case when whsworkline.workclassid = 'so pick' then whsworkline.workclosedutcdatetime else null end)) / (60 * 60 * 24)) + ':' +
 convert(varchar, dateadd(s, datediff(second,min(case when whsworkline.workclassid = 'so pick' then whsworkline.WORKINPROCESSUTCDATETIME else null end), max(case when whsworkline.workclassid = 'so pick' then whsworkline.workclosedutcdatetime else null end)), convert(datetime2, '0001-01-01')), 108) as 'Picking Time',

count(case when whsworkline.workclassid like '%Packing%' and whsworkline.worktype='1' then whsworkline.itemid    else null end) as 'Pallets Labeled' ,

convert(varchar, datediff(second,max(case when whsworkline.workclassid like '%so pick%' and whsworkline.worktype='2' then whsworkline.WORKCLOSEDUTCDATETIME else null end), max(case when whsworkline.workclassid like '%packing%' and whsworkline.worktype='2' then whsworkline.workclosedutcdatetime else null end)) / (60 * 60 * 24)) + ':' +
  convert(varchar, dateadd(s, datediff(second,max(case when whsworkline.workclassid like '%so pick%' and whsworkline.worktype='2' then whsworkline.WORKCLOSEDUTCDATETIME else null end), max(case when whsworkline.workclassid like '%packing%' and whsworkline.worktype='2' then whsworkline.workclosedutcdatetime else null end)), convert(datetime2, '0001-01-01')), 108) as 'Time In Labeling',

convert(varchar, datediff(SECOND,min( whsworkline.WORKINPROCESSUTCDATETIME ), max( whsworkline.workclosedutcdatetime)) / (60 * 60 * 24)) + ':' +
   convert(varchar, dateadd(s, datediff(SECOND,min( whsworkline.WORKINPROCESSUTCDATETIME ), max( whsworkline.workclosedutcdatetime)), convert(datetime2, '0001-01-01')), 108) 'WHS Work Time',

convert(varchar, datediff(SECOND,min( whsworkline.createddatetime ), max( whsworkline.workclosedutcdatetime)) / (60 * 60 * 24)) + ':' +
   convert(varchar, dateadd(s, datediff(SECOND,min( whsworkline.createddatetime ), max( whsworkline.workclosedutcdatetime)), convert(datetime2, '0001-01-01')), 108) 'Total WHS Time'

from whsworkline
   join salestable
   on whsworkline.ordernum=salestable.salesid
   join whswaveline
   on whsworkline.shipmentid=whswaveline.shipmentid
   join whswavetable
   on whswaveline.waveid=whswavetable.waveid
   where whsworkline.workclosedutcdatetime > '8/16/2017' and whsworkline.workclosedutcdatetime < '10/15/2017' and 
(whsworkline.workclassid = 'so pick' or whsworkline.workclassid = 'Stage' or whsworkline.workclassid = 'Packing')
group by whsworkline.shipmentid, whsworkline.ordernum, salestable.custaccount, whswaveline.waveid, whswavetable.wavetemplatename`

He and I are still trying to iron out a few details.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results in text form

Comment: Hey Daniel I tried to attach the sample data in the post. Can you see it clicking on the "enter image description here" links?

Comment: You need to copy it in text form to your post if you want people to help you

Comment: Sorry Im new to all this, Im not sure if thats what you mean or if theres a better way to do it. If so please let me know.

Comment: Also if you can let me know what else I need to include in order to show that Ive researched this? Ive scoured the internet to look for tips or instructions such as offsetting index columns or pivots, but I didnt want to make the post so long to where people didnt even read it. Again any help or pointers youve got would be great.

Comment: Basically you want to specify a clear question, provide sample data in text form that can be easily copy/pasted and entered into a db, and provide your desired results

Comment: Ok let me revise and see if I can clean this up.

Comment: Hey Daniel let me know if that makes it easier, thanks again for the pointers.

Comment: A little better - I'll work on this for you

Comment: Thanks boss. If there is something else I can to do help or clean up just let me know. Also there is more data in that particular table but that is what I pull, so if theres something else you think would help let me know, the data may be there and Im just not pulling it.

Comment: In your first example Shipment SH-000026373  where are you getting 13 seconds for 'so pick time' from?

Comment: Also where is your data for SH-000045099?  I need and exact sample of data going in and the exact expected results please

Comment: Sorry the times were random, I was basically saying the difference between the "ClosedWork" time of the first line of that shipment to the "Closedwork" time of the next line. SH-000045099 was just there as an example of what other works look like, I tried to upload that full pull but got a message saying I exceeded the number of allowable characters. Do you know a way I can up load the full pull?

Comment: Just pull a few sample shipments with all the data going in and the expected results

Comment: Working on it now, just a few minutes more

Comment: Ok Daniel made the edits to reflect the actual data. I edited the SQL query in so much as to pull specific shipments and expanded the dates to get the correct examples but other than that SQL statement didnt change.

Comment: Also just wanted to point out that as far as calculating the lines for each "WorkClassID" Im only including where the "Worktype" is 1. To calculate the time for each "Workclassid" I basically took the time of the last "WorkType 2" and subtracted the time of the first "WorkType 1". Then the total time at the very end was the last "WorkType 2" minus the first "WorkType 1" for the entire shipment. Make sense?

Comment: Please cleanup the data so I can see what's in each column.  The bulkpack lines for example have only 7 inputs.

Comment: Not to be difficult here but do you have a better suggestion of how to do that? In order to get it all on here I basically just copy and pasted it between two ` symbols. When Im in the post and copy and paste that data into excel it lines up. Some lines will be blank though, for instance the itemid column will be blank if it has more than one item for a put.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select shipmentid, itemid, qtywork, wmslocationid, workclassid, workstatus, workclosedutcdatetime, worktype into #temp
from whsworkline
where workclosedutcdatetime > '9/17/2017' and workclosedutcdatetime < '9/24/2017' and workclassid = 'so pick'
order by shipmentid, workclosedutcdatetime
```

How does this work for you?  Times are just in hours for now but can be adjusted if this works.  Assume #temp is the result of your original query and we start working from there:

```
        select shipmentid,  count(distinct case when  workclassid='so' and worktype=1 then null else itemid end ) [# of SO Picks], 

convert(varchar, datediff(s, min(case when workclassid = 'so' then workclosedutcdatetime else null end), 
max(case when workclassid = 'so' then workclosedutcdatetime else null end)) / (60 * 60 * 24)) + ':'
+ convert(varchar, dateadd(s, datediff(s, min(case when workclassid = 'so' then workclosedutcdatetime else null end), 
max(case when workclassid = 'so' then workclosedutcdatetime else null end)), convert(datetime2, '0001-01-01')), 108)  [SO Pick Time] ,

count(distinct case when workstatus like '%stage%' then itemid    else null end) [# of Stage Lines],

convert(varchar, datediff(s, min(case when workstatus like '%stage%' then workclosedutcdatetime else null end), 
max(case when workstatus like '%stage%' then workclosedutcdatetime else null end)) / (60 * 60 * 24)) + ':'
+ convert(varchar, dateadd(s, datediff(s, min(case when workstatus like '%stage%' then workclosedutcdatetime else null end), 
max(case when workstatus like '%stage%' then workclosedutcdatetime else null end)), convert(datetime2, '0001-01-01')), 108) [Stage Time] ,

count(distinct case when workstatus like '%packing%' then itemid else null end) [# of Packing lines],

convert(varchar, datediff(s, min(case when workstatus like '%packing%' then workclosedutcdatetime else null end), 
max(case when  workstatus like '%packing%' then workclosedutcdatetime else null end)) / (60 * 60 * 24)) + ':'
+ convert(varchar, dateadd(s, datediff(s, min(case when workstatus like '%packing%' then workclosedutcdatetime else null end), 
max(case when workstatus like '%packing%' then workclosedutcdatetime else null end)), convert(datetime2, '0001-01-01')), 108) [Packing Time],

convert(varchar, datediff(s, min(workclosedutcdatetime), 
max(workclosedutcdatetime)) / (60 * 60 * 24)) + ':'
+ convert(varchar, dateadd(s, datediff(s, min(workclosedutcdatetime), 
max(workclosedutcdatetime)), convert(datetime2, '0001-01-01')), 108) [Total time of shipment]

from #temp 
group by shipmentid
```

Comment: Daniel, Im not sure if interpretted it the right way but where you had "from #temp" I input my original query in parenthesis. Or was that an incorrect assumption? This is what the query looks like currently:

Comment: Sorry its telling me my comment is too long, Im just trying to paste the query as I ran it. I got an error saying the order by clause is invalid

Comment: Ok I feel like were starting to get somewhere, I realized though I had to make a few changes to the original query since it was only pulling "SO Picks" this is what I ammended the original query too...

Comment: `select shipmentid, itemid, qtywork, wmslocationid, workclassid, workstatus, workclosedutcdatetime, worktype
from whsworkline
where workclosedutcdatetime > '8/16/2017' and workclosedutcdatetime < '10/15/2017' and 
(workclassid = 'so pick' or workclassid = 'Stage' or workclassid = 'Packing')
order by shipmentid, workclosedutcdatetime`

Comment: Im sorry, one more question, how are you able to fit your entire query into one comment section? I cannot do the same as you have it formatted in yours. Im trying to make it easy for you to just copy and paste

Comment: You have to put updated queries in your original post space - comments are not for code

Comment: Updated again to show field names and display time differences in dd:hh:mm:ss format

Comment: Im curious, in the first part of your answer "Count(distinct case...."

Could you instead do a case statement with an "and"? For instance, if I wanted to 

Count(case when workclassid='so pick' and worktype='1' then null else workclassid end)

Comment: sure put any condition you want in there and it will only count records that fulfill that condition

Comment: How would I write that though, I get an error when trying to add an "and" in the case statement. So if I wanted to count the distinct instances where a workclassid was "SO Pick" and where the workType was "1", how would I construct that?

Comment: Hey Daniel, I wanted to say thanks for all your help. Im making some good progress. I have another question for you though, Ive got a good bit of this worked out but I need to bring a column in from another table so I did a join, but it basically multiplies all my results by 3. Any ideas on how I can correct that?

Comment: What that means is that you have multiple values in the new table that join to a record in the original table - make sure all records in the new table only join once to the original table

Comment: Also if my answer worked for you , please accept and upvote thanks

Comment: Absolutely, it definitely got me on the right track. Ill also post the final product I came to with your help. I do have one final question here though, if you wanted to calculate the time differently instead of dd:hh:mm:ss, go instead with hh:mm:ss how would I edit the query? I have tried a few different ways and can not get it to work.

Comment: Try replacing (60 * 60 * 24) with  (60 * 24)

Comment: Thanks Daniel, Ill give that a shot. One question, when I tried to expand the dates of my query i got this error message:

Msg 535, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok Daniel, I copy and pasted the entire query that Im using now in the bottom of the post. I had to delete some earlier information because I had exceeded the 30000 character limit. So when Im just looking up a few specific shipments it works great. But then as soon as I try to expand my date range to include more shipments it gives me that overflow error. It will populate some rows of data first and then error out. So I know its working, but just errors out for overflow.